# Is there a faster way to access objects exposed by VSTO/Excel

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto, excel-addins

I'm writing a lot of Office add-ins in C#, and I love all the wonderful ways you can extend the functionality of especially Excel. But one thing that keeps bugging me is the overhead of doing pretty much anything to pretty much any Office object.

I'm aware that there are high-level tricks to doing many things faster, like reading and writing `object[,]` arrays to larger cell ranges instead of accessing individual cells, and so on. But regardless, a complicated add-in will always end up accessing lots of different objects, or many properties of a few objects, or the same properties over and over again.

And when profiling my add-ins I always find I spend at least 90% of my CPU time accessing basic properties of Office objects. For instance, here is a bit of code I use to check if a window has been scrolled, so I can update some overlay graphics accordingly:

```
Excel.Window window = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow;

if (window.ScrollColumn != previousScrollColumn)
{
    needsRedraw = true;
    previousScrollColumn = window.ScrollColumn;
}

if (window.ScrollRow != previousScrollRow)
{
    needsRedraw = true;
    previousScrollRow = window.ScrollRow;
}

if (window.Zoom != previousZoom)
{
    needsRedraw = true;
    previousZoom = window.Zoom;
}
```

The first line, getting the active window, and each of the if statements, each accessing a property of that window, all light up when profiling. They're really slow.

Now I know these are COM objects in managed wrappers, and there's some sort of managed->unmanaged interface stuff going on, probably inter-process communication and whatnot, so I'm not surprised that there's some overhead, but I'm still amazed at how much it adds up.

So are there any tricks for speeding stuff like this up?

For instance, in the above case I'm accessing three properties of the same object. I can't help but think there must be some way to read them all in one go, like maybe via a native companion add-in or something...?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the Open XML, you can load it and traverse it using the Open XML SDK or other related libraries. Word has this (`Range.WordOpenXML`) but I don't know if Excel does. Even then, it might be that not all properties are exposed, for example the scroll location is probably not there.

Comment: Sadly it appears that Excel doesn't have any properties like that. :(